# How to check gpu usages on aws ec2 gpu instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, cpu-usage

I'm running a ubuntu gpu instance on AWS ec2. I'm not sure if my application is using gpu accelerations. So how to check gpu usages on aws gpu instance?

Answer (score 6):

- Use: `nvidia-smi -h` to see the options.
- Display info arguments:

```
Display only selected information: MEMORY,
                                    UTILIZATION, ECC, TEMPERATURE, POWER, CLOCK,
                                    COMPUTE, PIDS, PERFORMANCE, SUPPORTED_CLOCKS,
                                    PAGE_RETIREMENT, ACCOUNTING, ENCODER STATS
```

- Example: `nvidia-smi --id=0 --loop=5 --query --display=UTILIZATION`

  - `--id=0` the number of the GPU. Use `nvidia-smi --list-gpus` to get the list of GPUs
  - `--query` display GPU or unit information
  - `--loop=5` repeat the query every 5 seconds.
  - `-display=UTILIZATION` display only utilization
- The output is something like:

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Thu Apr 11 03:48:37 2019
Driver Version                      : 384.183
CUDA Version                        : 9.0

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 00000000:00:1E.0
    Utilization
        **Gpu                         : 9 %**
        Memory                      : 11 %
        Encoder                     : 0 %
        Decoder                     : 0 %
    GPU Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 18446744073709.22 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 10 %
        Min                         : 0 %
        Avg                         : 0 %
    Memory Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 18446744073709.22 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 14 %
        Min                         : 0 %
        Avg                         : 0 %
    ENC Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 18446744073709.22 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 0 %
        Min                         : 0 %
        Avg                         : 0 %
    DEC Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 18446744073709.22 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 0 %
        Min                         : 0 %
        Avg                         : 0 %
```

You can also log to a file (`--filename=`) and output CSV (`--format=csv`).

Answer (score 3):

Is this NVIDIA gear? If so, try `nvidia-smi -i 3 -l -q -d` to see GPU and memory utilization statistics (among other info). 
Notice that this only works under 1) old nvidia drivers (18X.XX), or 2) NVIDIA Tesla GPUs.

Comment: It returns:
Missing value for -d argument. Please run 'nvidia-smi -h' for help.